# $x^{p^{2}}-p^{p}$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{Q} [x]$

Tags: polynomials, irreducible-polynomials

Let $p$ be a prime number in $\mathbb{N}$.

How to show that $x^{p^{2}}-p^{p}$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{Q} [x]$ ?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: Thank you your comment.

Comment: Do you know a polynomial whose $(p^p)^{1/p^2}$ is a root ?

Comment: Is that $X^p-p$ ? I didn't notice it. So you want to say that $x^{p^2}-p^p$ is not irreducible polynomial, right?

Comment: Well if $p=2$ this reduces to $x^4-4=(x^2+2)(x^2-2)$ so I guess you might want $p$ to be an odd prime.

Comment: Even if $p$ is an odd prime, I found that $x^{p^2}-p^p$ is not irreducible. For example, if $p=3$, $x^{3^2}-3^3=x^9-27=(x^3-3)(x^6+3x^3+9)$. So my claim is totally incorrect. I should have thought before asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have
$$
(x^p)^p-p^p=(x^p-p)((x^p)^{p-1}+p(x^p)^{p-2}+\cdots+p^{p-2}(x^p)+p^{p-1})
$$
meaning the polynomial is reducible.

Answer (score 0):

For $p=2$:
$$x^{2^2}-2^2=x^4-4=(x^2+2)(x^2-2)$$

For $p=3$:
$$x^{3^2}-3^3=x^9-27=(x^3-3)(x^6+3x^3+9)$$

For $p=5$:
$$x^{5^2}-5^5=x^{25}-3125=(x^5-5)(x^{20}+5x^{15}+25x^{10}+125x^{5}+625)$$

In fact, $x^{p^2}-p^p=(x^p-p)\sum_{i=0}^{p-1}(p^ix^{p^2-(i+1)p})$

The polynomial is always factorizable into two smaller polynomials with integer coefficients.  However, these smaller polynomials have no rational roots.